# How does angularjs routing work?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have the following application config, the otherwise section seem to win all the time Why details are not matching here?:

```
var app = angular.module("atTheMovies", ["ngRoute"]);
var config = function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {        
    $routeProvider
    .when('/list',
        { templateUrl: "/client/views/list.html" }
    )
    .when("/details/:id",
        { templateUrl: "/client/views/details.html" })
    .otherwise(
        { redirectTo: "/list" });

    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')
}
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",config]);
```

My anchor tags href are like this:

```
<a href="#/details/1">Details</a>
<a href="#/details/2">Details</a>
<a href="#/details/3">Details</a>
```

Comment: What is the problem, What are you trying to do that isnt happening?

Comment: Was trying to follow single page application example. href in any of my tag does not match the second when. It always fall in the otherwise then go to list.

Comment: Did you try only putting `<a href="details/1">Details</a>` without #??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `href` without putting `#`

```
<a href="details/1">Details</a>
<a href="details/2">Details</a>
<a href="details/3">Details</a>
```

A Plunker example here
**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WEZsRWB9Z4GoOf7YLgwm?p=preview)**

Comment: This is confusing, something is said about old browsers using # or one can enable html5mode on location provider. Where can I read more about this routing thing. This works perfectly well, thanks.